# 2 subscriptions "Microsoft Azure" & "Pay-As-You-Go" when creating Azure App Service, which one to chose to host sharepoint remote event receiver

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-web-app-service

I want to deploy our SharePoint remote event receiver inside an Azure web app. but when i create a new web app i got 2 subscriptions ("Microsoft Azure" OR "Pay-As-You-Go"), as follow:-

[image: o]

So i am not sure what are the main differences between these 2 subscriptions?

second question; which one is more suitable for hosting SharePoint remote event receivers?

Answer (score 2):

Pay as you go is just like it says, you pay for only the services that you use, based on the pricing for that service.  More info [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0003p/).

A subscription is [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/guides/developer/azure-developer-guide#understanding-accounts-subscriptions-and-billing)  "a logical grouping of Azure services that is linked to an Azure account. A single Azure account can contain multiple subscriptions. Billing for Azure services is done on a per-subscription basis. For a list of the available subscription offers by type, see [Microsoft Azure Offer Details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/offer-details/)"

You have two subscriptions set up.  On is a pay as you go subscription, and one is another type, although I'm not sure what.  There should be no difference which one you select from a technical standpoint.  It is only a matter of how you want to be billed.  Azure web apps have a free tier as well.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply,, but how i can know if i am using the free tier for our web apps? second question, how i can know how much our web app have consumed or cost so far, as inside the cost management, the MS Azure subscription is not listed inside the scope list...

Comment: There's a lot to unpack in your questions.  However, most of what you're asking can be answered with the provided documentation.  I may be able to jump in and try to answer some later tonight

Comment: When you create an Azure web app you select a service plan. The service plan has a free  teir, but the resources are limited.  Supposed to be for development

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical difference between the two subscriptions. There might be a difference with regards to support levels or service level agreements (SLAs), e.g. if one of them is a Dev/Test subscription. There might be a difference in "purpose" - one might be exclusively for "production use cases", while the other might be for testing. There is no way for us to know.

You really should ask the person responsible for the Azure subscriptions on which one you should use. If you set them up yourself, you take a more detailed look at the subscriptions themselves.